# New to Data Warehousing and Data Marts

Tags: data-warehouse, dimension, fact, scd

I'm completely new to Data Warehousing and Marts and wanted to ask for some advice on the best resources to learn and gain knowledge to start me off on the right path. I have a project to work on but need some guidance or somewhere to start really.

The problem is I've been given a matter of weeks to create a small mart with Fact and Dims then need to write stored procs for a GUI to feed in and out of this. I need to know how to create a scripted SCD which I have a basic idea and can use MERGE scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for *free* resources.

You can start with [Kimball Dimensional Modeling Techniques](http://www.kimballgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/2013.09-Kimball-Dimensional-Modeling-Techniques11.pdf). Check also [SCD not easy as 1, 2, 3](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2005/03/slowly-changing-dimensions-are-not-always-as-easy-as-1-2-3/) and [Slowly Changing Dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/08/slowly-changing-dimensions/).

Since you need to design [Fact tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905984(v=sql.80).aspx) and [Dimension tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905979(v=sql.80).aspx) would be hepful as well.

Do you have any concrete assignments and if yes, you can show what you've done so far.